# Using HttpModule instead of Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I convert:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {


    }

</script>
```

To a scheme that uses HttpModule?

Also, can I write the Global.asax as pure C# instead of using tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the init of your custom module you need to retrieve the Session-module and add an event handler for the Start event.

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(Begin_Request);
    IHttpModule sessionModule = context.Modules["Session"];
    if(sessionModule != null && 
        sessionModule.GetType() == typeof(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule))
    {
        (sessionModule as System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule).Start 
          += new EventHandler(CustomHttpModule_Start);
    }
}
```

> Also, can I write the Global.asax aspure C# instead of using tags?

Yes you can add a code behind in the in the Global.asax and change the content to

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" CodeBehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Global" %>
```

Your code behind should inherit from System.Web.HttpApplication

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
  public Global()   {   }

  void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // Code that runs when a new session is started
  }
}
```